# Creating two new elements using JS

Tags: javascript

New to JavaScript. This is a flashcard like program and I need to create a new div element and a new img element for each individual img. I've managed to get the correct number of divs but now I'm struggling to get an img element to do under the div. How can I fix the code to get an img under each div? Also how do I append the img without having an id or do I have to have an id? I would really appreciate the help.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'frame');
  document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(newDiv);
  var newImg = document.createElement('img');
  newImg.setAttribute('src', personArray[i].url);
  newImg.setAttribute('onclick', 'promptForName(this)');
  newImg.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'styleIt(this)');
  newImg.setAttribute('onmouseout', 'unStyleIt(this)');
  newImg.setAttribute('id', personArray[i].firstname);
  document.getElementById('').appendChild(newImg);

}
```

Here is the [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/suyovudele/edit?html,output) code.

Comment: You don't have to have an ID, you could use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find any element you want. Although do you not want it to go inside the div you've just created? Or the same parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the element you want added to HTML ready before appending them into an element.

With that said, you want to:

1. Create `<div>` element and modify it to the way you want it to be
2. Create `<img>` element and modify it to the way you want it to be
3. Append #2 (`<img>`) into element #1 (`<div>`) by calling `newDiv.appendChild(newImg)`
4. Append element #1 (`<div>`) into HTML document

See example below.

```js
var currentId = "";
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

var personArray = [
  {
    firstname: "Ann",
    url:
      "http://www.tuktukdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/person-icon.jpg"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Jane",
    url:
      "http://www.tuktukdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/person-icon.jpg"
  },
  {
    firstname: "John",
    url:
      "http://www.tuktukdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/person-icon.jpg"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Joe",
    url:
      "http://www.tuktukdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/person-icon.jpg"
  }
];

function populateImages() {
  for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("class", "frame");
    var newImg = document.createElement("img");
    newImg.setAttribute("src", personArray[i].url);
    newImg.setAttribute("onclick", "promptForName(this)");
    newImg.setAttribute("onmouseover", "styleIt(this)");
    newImg.setAttribute("onmouseout", "unStyleIt(this)");
    newImg.setAttribute("id", personArray[i].firstname);
    newDiv.appendChild(newImg);
    document.getElementById("pic-grid").appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}

function promptForName(element) {
  document.getElementById("response").value = "";
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("prompt").style.display = "block";
  currentId = element.id;
  x = element.offsetLeft;
  y = element.offsetTop;
  x = x + 20;
  y = y + 20;
  document.getElementById("prompt").style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById("prompt").style.top = y;
  document.getElementById("prompt").style.left = x;
  document.getElementById("response").focus();
}

function styleIt(element) {
  element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
}

function unStyleIt(element) {
  element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

function checkAnswer() {
  if (
    document.getElementById("response").value ==
    personArray[currentId].firstname
  ) {
    document.getElementById(currentId).className = "opClass";
    document.getElementById(currentId).removeAttribute("onclick");
    document.getElementById(currentId).removeAttribute("onmouseover");

    var divVar = document.createElement("div");
    divVar.setAttribute("id", currentId + "name");
    document.getElementById("pic-grid").appendChild(divVar);
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(personArray[currentId].firstname);
    divVar.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById(currentId + "name").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById(currentId + "name").style.top = y;
    document.getElementById(currentId + "name").style.left = x;

    document.getElementById("prompt").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(currentId).parentNode.style.backgroundColor =
      "white";
    document.getElementById("response").value = "";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    if (document.getElementById("message").innerHTML == "Wrong!") {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Incorrect answer!";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Wrong!";
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
body,
header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: silver;
}

.frame {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#prompt {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.opClass {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<body onload="populateImages()">
 <header>
  <h2>Class Flashcards</h2>
  <h3>Click on a student to guess their name</h3>
 </header>

 <div id="pic-grid">

 </div>

 <div id="prompt">
  What is this student's name?<br />
  <form onsubmit="return checkAnswer()">
   <input type="text" id="response" name="quizInput">
  </form>
  <div id="message"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `document.getElementById`, or any of the element queries, will result in the actual element being returned. So to, using `document.createElement` also returns an element (of which you used in your code example).

Simply re use the element that you created to append the image with.

```
newDiv.appendChild(newImg);
```